# Force refresh proxy settings file in iOS 8

Tags: iphone, xcode, proxy, ios8, settings

Is there any possibility to force refresh proxy settings file (programmatically of course) in iOS 8? In previous versions of iOS, file was refreshed each time at startup of any app, but now it's downloaded only once and cached when iPhone connects to wifi network (only way to refresh it is reconnect with wifi or connect to VPN).

Thanks in advance for help.